# Encoding UTF8 weird characters?

Tags: c#

I am working TAPI API in c#. One of the call property has `byte[]` data and I am converting that into string format. The string is JSON format. 
Everything is working fine my machine. But When I ran the same code it different machine it string (JSON) format showing in weird characters.

Please see both below

### Code

```
// This event handler is called when a new incoming call is received.
void OnIncomingCall(object sender, TapiEventArgs args)
{
   // Display message in the log
   string msg;
   msg = String.Format("Incoming call from {0} {1} on line '{2}'. and {3}",
        args.Call.CallerIDName, args.Call.CallerID,
        args.Line.Name.Clone(),args.Call.Tag);
   msg = msg + "\n" + string.Format("DeviceSpecificInfo data is {0}", 
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Call.DeviceSpecificInfo));

                    AddToLog(msg);
                }
```

### My machine

[image]

image url for [My machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysi9O.png)

### Other Machine

[image]

image url for [Other machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8G67.png)

What could be the issue? Is it encode issue?

Comment: Can't see..too small. Try copy pasta.

Comment: You cannot read arbitrary binary data as UTF8.  You may want Base65.

Comment: Obviously the second `byte[]` is not JSON, but some binary format — BSON? Protobuf?

Comment: It is "device specific".  Give the TSP vendor a call if you want to know how it is formatted.

Comment: I added image urls below the image. Please check them

Comment: Anyone complaining on Imagesize just needs to rightclick => Show Image

Comment: As @HansPassant said, it's device-specific. See http://www.traysoft.com/devtools/addtapi/manual/Help/Html/94101b3b-f036-9ca2-085e-175ffb09e39d.htm. You have to handle it differently for each type of device.